# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath invoked multiple times if it's a manual call?

Tags: ios5, uitableview

If I have UITableView as a property of a UIViewController and I'm manually accessing a cell at a particular row with `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.

On one method invoke, should I expect to see multiple calls to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Each of my UITableViewCell has a UITextField whose text data I'm trying to access.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
for (int section = 0; ix < countOfSections; ++section)
{
    NSInteger countOfRowsInSection = // attained
    for (int row = 0; row < countOfRowsInSection; ++row)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

        // the follow call seems to elicit multiple invocations 
        // on my table delegate's
        // - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Access some custom data
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to access all of the data stored in the UITextField each of the UITableViewCell for all sections & rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be trying to use views for data storage.  In whatever you're using as the table's data source there should be an array (or other structure) of objects that contains the data that provides content for the cells when `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

If you need other access to that information, you should be getting it directly from the data structure rather than the display.

Comment: The content is provided by the user and is stored in the UITextField held inside UITableViewCell. I was under the impression that it's bad to hold onto these UITextField elements outside of their respective UITableViewCell.

Comment: The text fields belong to the cells because they're part of the view but, unless your app structure is very unusual, the actual text should be managed as part of the application's data model.  Your current problem is one symptom but things will get extremely difficult if, for example, you have enough cells to require scrolling.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is figure out a reasonable way to go capture the text entered by the user into the UITextField. If the data originates from the user, what would be a good way to do this? I don't understand how I can manage the data until I have access to it.

Comment: I'd consider registering a `UITextFieldDelegate` and responding to events to update the data model.  (What should act as the delegate depends on the application design, maybe the view controller or maybe a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`.)